# How can I get multiple names of ARReferenceImages to return the same data from a JSON file?

Tags: json, swift, arkit

Let's say my JSON file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Composting Toilet",
    "saving": "3",
    "type": "Water"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ceiling Fans",
    "saving": "4",
    "type": "Energy"
  },
  {
    "name": "Solar Canopy",
    "saving": "5",
    "type": "Energy"
  },
  {
    "name": "Waste Bins",
    "saving": "6",
    "type": "Materials"
  }
]
```

I want to have AR Resource Images named 'Composting Toilet0', 'Composting Toilet1' that lets me return the data for Composting Toilet. The same goes for the rest of the names.

Right now, my code works by checking if the ARResource Image name is equal to the name category of the JSON file, and if it is, then it returns the data associated with that name. I am thinking of assigning each 'version' of the AR Resource Image a number and then creating conditionals that say, if the AR Resource Image is associated with numbers 0-3 then return the data from Composting Toilet, if the Image is associated with numbers 4-7, return the data from Ceiling Fans, etc.

```
func getInfo(detectedObject: ARReferenceImage) -> String{
        print(detectedObject)
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "LivingBuildingData", ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)

                if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? [[String: Any]] {
                    for res in jsonResult {
                        let jsonEntryName = res["name"] as! String

                        if (jsonEntryName == detectedObject.name) {
                            print("success")

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.informationView.setName(name: "\(res["name"] as! String)")
                                self.informationView.setSaving(saving: "Saving: \(res["saving"] as! String)")
                                self.informationView.setType(type: "Type: \(res["type"] as! String)")
                            }

                            return jsonEntryName
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                objc_exception_throw("Data does not exist!")
            }
        }
        return "Err"
    }
```

I expect to be able to input AR Resource Images that look like 'Solar Canopy0', 'Solar Canopy1', 'Ceiling Fans0', 'Composting Toilet0', etc. and be able to set the data for those specific objects from the JSON File.